# Grabbing a value from SQLite database using a cursor and converting to int

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This may not be the best approach to grabbing a value from a column in a database but here's what I have so far:

I have a table called switches with a column called levels. The column levels is an integer value column. I want to grab the integer values from the levels column. How can I do that? I tried this but I am unable to just get the integer value vs. getting the Cursor.

Here's my code:

```
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
            sqLiteDatabase = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
            sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
            Cursor cursor;
            Integer level;

            String select_level = "SELECT level FROM switches";

            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_level, null);
            level = Integer.parseInt(cursor.toString());
```

The problem is Cursor is not an integer, so I thought to convert to string then int but it seems like I get a number format exception. I think it's because the cursor is giving me the column name and the integer value.

How do I just grab the integer value for a specific column using raw SQL with SQLite database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this line of code,

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_level, null);
```

Add the below code

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
level = cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

Comment: oh I see, if what I want to populate a list such that, if I had several levels and I want to put the levels I get from the database into a list?

Comment: that is, the above is giving me the last value in the db table for some reason. What if I wanted the first value?

Comment: @Euridice01, To get the first value from db, modify the select query accordingly. May be Order by Asc would also help. ... Or in the while statement add a break statement after assigment. That will solve your purpose.